# Using const int variable in switch statement

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I am using gcc with the -std=c++11 flag. In my class definition I have the following:

```
private:
   const int   January     = 1,
               February    = 2,
               March       = 3,
               ...
```

In my implementation I have a switch statement.

```
switch (currentMonth)
{
   case January:
      returnString = "January";
      break;
   case February:
      returnString = "February";
      break;
   case March:
      returnString = "March";
      break;
   ...
```

This seems like it should work since the months are constant; however, gcc gives me

```
calendar.cpp:116:12: error: ‘this’ is not a constant expression
```

on each case of the switch statement..Why is this wrong?

Comment: which line in your example is `116`, is it on one if the assignments? or a case of the `switch` itself?

Comment: I edited the post to be more clear

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Non-static class members aren't constant expressions. Try this:

```
static constexpr int January = 1;
```

Comment: +1, this is probably it. As a note, for something c++03 compatible, `static const int January = 1;` will work as well.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `static` keyword, but I was under the impression that using `new` creates a static object; so does that mean this would be the same as using `new`? Which would mean that in my destructor I would need to call delete on each of these? Or is that completely different?

Comment: @kennycoc: No, using `new` does not create a static object, where did you hear that?

Comment: I'm in the process of learning C++ through pluralsight. I'm sure I just misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
enum {
 January = 1,
 February = 2
 ...
};
```

Comment: Better still, try something that will compile.

Comment: `enum int` should just be `enum` (or, in C++11, perhaps `enum : int` if you particularly want the underlying type to be `int` for some reason), and it needs a semicolon after the declaration.

Comment: If you have a browser and an internet connection, then you have access to a compiler. Many, actually.  For example: http://ideone.com/

Comment: @BenjaminLindley cool, thanks. I only knew about jsfiddle and repl.it

Comment: some update for those who will look this up: use `enum class` instead of `enum`, it gives you the type check